# Djagno Rest Framework Serialization only reading in first column

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to read in data from a list into a serializer. When the method is executed below it only appends the name of the dashboard to my widgets_value table. A little bit about `widget_endpoint_post` method it first takes in a request object that looks like

request object

```
{'dashboard_name': 'check_out', 'widgets': [{'position': {'top': 1, 'left': 1, 'width': 1, 'height': 1}, 'name': 0, 'content': {}, 'public_private': '', 'owner': '', 'title': ''}], 'type': 'public', 'user': 'Person_1'}
```

The method below uses two serializers one to create a table to reference a dashboard another to save each dashboard's layout

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def widget_endpoint_post(request):
    body_unicode = request.body.decode('utf-8')
    body = json.loads(body_unicode)
    serializer=AddDashboardSerializer(data=request.data)
    data={}

    if serializer.is_valid():
        account=serializer.save()
        body['dashboard_name']=account.dashboard_name
        body['user']=account.user
        body['type']=account.type
        print('test')
    else:
        data = serializer.errors


    print(body['widgets'])
    # print(body['widgets'])
    for x in range(len(body['widgets'])):
        print(body['widgets'][x]['position']['top'])

        serializer2=AddWidgitSerializer(data=request.data)
        data={}
        if serializer2.is_valid():
            account=serializer2.save()
            body['dashboard_name'] = account.dashboard_name
            body['type'] = account.widget_type
            body['user'] = account.owner
            body['widgets'][x]['name'] = account.widget_name
            body['widgets'][x]['position']['top'] = account.top
            body['widgets'][x]['position']['left'] = account.left
            body['widgets'][x]['position']['width']=account.width
            body['widgets'][x]['position']['height']=account.height

        else:
            data=serializer.errors

    return Response('Dashboard saved')
```

serializers.py

```
class AddDashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dashboard_name=serializers.CharField(),
    user=serializers.CharField(),
    type=serializers.CharField(),
    class Meta:
        model= DashboardView
        fields=['dashboard_name','user','type']


class AddWidgitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dashboard_name=serializers.CharField(),
    widget_name=serializers.CharField(),
    top=serializers.CharField(),
    left=serializers.CharField(),
    height=serializers.CharField(),
    width=serializers.CharField(),
    widget_type=serializers.CharField(),
    owner=serializers.CharField(),
    class Meta:
        model=WidgetView
        fields=['dashboard_name','widget_name','top','left','height','width','widget_type','owner']
```

Below is the WidgetView table it only validates the name of the dashboard and I don't know why.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
class AddDashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    dashboard_name = serializers.CharField()
    user = serializers.CharField()
    type = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = DashboardView
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   for x in range(len(body['widgets'])):
               WidgetView.objects.bulk_create([
                   WidgetView(dashboard_name=body['dashboard_name'],widget_name=body['user'],top=body['widgets'][x]['position']['top'],
                                                                            left=body['widgets'][x]['position']['left'],
                                                                            height=body['widgets'][x]['position']['height'],
                                                                           width=body['widgets'][x]['position']['width'],
                                                                           widget_type=body['type'],
                                                                           owner=body['user'])
               ])
```